# Inject IOwinContext with Web API and Ninject

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject, owin

Using Web API 2 and OWIN hosting with Ninject.

I would like to inject the current IOwinContext into certain services (so I can get at the Request to get the principal to do some data filtering).

With Web Hosting I would, in the old days, simply have used HttpContext.Current but that is not an option with OWIN hosting (and good riddance).

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703268/resolving-iowincontext-in-mvc5-application-using-autofac) explains how to do it with Autofac. Essentially, you create a Dependency Scope and then, on each request, calls Autofac's Registerinstance to register the current IOwinContext into that dependency scope like so:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    // this creates a per-request, disposable scope
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(b =>
    {
        // this makes owin context resolvable in the scope
        b.RegisterInstance(ctx).As<IOwinContext>();
    }))
    {
        // this makes scope available for downstream frameworks
        ctx.Set<ILifetimeScope>("idsrv:AutofacScope", scope);
        await next();
    }
});
```

That is very elegant. With Ninject and the Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHosting I already get a named scope for each request so that plumbing is taken care of. However, I haven't been able to find any way in ninject to mirror AutoFac's RegisterInstance method: The key here is that this binding is only valid within this particular dependency scope.

I have read up on the various options around Scope but everything I have found relies on being able to declare constants or ToMethod. What I am looking to do here is to say, "okay, I now have a ninject dependency scope and if anyone asks for an IOwinContext from *this* scope, give them this instance that I already have.

#### Note

I do understand that I can get the current context from within my controller and pass it on, but that rather defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do; I want my DbContext to understand who the user is so it can filter the data. And, of course, once I can get the IOwinContext I won't actually pass that to the DbContext, rather I will use a ToMethod or similar to extract the ClaimsPrincipal but that is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: This is a hack. It works, but it feels very unclean. Use at your peril.

In essence, you can create an OwinContextHolder class, bind it InRequestScope and use a DelegatingHandler to populate it on each request. Something like this:

```
public class OwinContextHolder
{
    public IOwinContext OwinContext { get; set; }
}

public class OwinContextHolderModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        // Instead of a NinjectModule you can of course just register the service
        this.Kernel.Bind<OwinContextHolder>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

Your delegating handler:

```
public class SetOwinContextHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var holder = request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(OwinContextHolder)) as OwinContextHolder;
        if (holder != null)
        {
            holder.OwinContext = request.GetOwinContext();
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Finally add the DelegatingHandler to your Startup class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var webApiConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
    webApiConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...);

    webApiConfiguration.MessageHandlers.Add(new SetOwinContextHandler());

    app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
    app.UseNinjectWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
}
```

You can now inject OwinContextHolder into your classes.

Note that if you have your API in a separate assembly from your host, you may have problems with InRequestScope silently not working (as in, you get a different object every time you request one and no errors). If you do, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ninject/Wmy83BhhFz8.

Comment: Time to switch Injection Frameworks.  Autofac does this without such tricks.